# Function to count faces in firebase_ml_vision on Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-mlkit

I am currently working on an app which requires to count the faces on the screen. I am using the firebase_ml_vision plugin in Flutter. I've tried the trackng ID method bu i didn't work out. Does someone know how to count the faces?

Answer (score 1):

But interface defines returned type as List.

```
final List<Face> faces = await faceDetector.processImage(visionImage);
print(faces.length)
```